# Pass array data from javascript in browser to spring mvc controller using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays, spring-mvc

I would like to pass an array from javascript in web browser to a Spring MVC controller using AJAX

In javascript, I have

```
var a = [];
a[0] = 1;
a[1] = 2;
a[2] = 3;

// how about multiple arrays as well?

$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "/myurl",
    data : //not sure how to write this, ("a="+a), ?
    success : function(response) {
       // do something ... 
    },
    error : function(e) {
       alert('Error: ' + e);
    }
});
```

In Java, I would like to create a class to receive data from AJAX, and I create a class to receive data

```
package com.amazon.infratool.ui;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;


@Setter @Getter
public class RepairInfomationParameters {
//how to write this variable?
    List<String> a = null; // is it something like this?
}
```

What is the correct way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 34):

You can do this from the JavaScript side:

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "/myurl",
    data : {
        myArray: a //notice that "myArray" matches the value for @RequestParam
                   //on the Java side
    },
    success : function(response) {
       // do something ... 
    },
    error : function(e) {
       alert('Error: ' + e);
    }
});
```

Then on the Java side (in Spring 3), assuming that this method is mapped by `/myurl`:

```
public String controllerMethod(@RequestParam(value="myArray[]") Integer[] myArray){
    ....
}
```

I believe the following will also work:

```
public String controllerMethod(@RequestParam(value="myArray[]") List<Integer> myArray){
    ....
}
```

Spring is smart enough to figure out how to do the binding.

For multiple arrays, you might want to just have a command object:

```
public class MyData {
    private List<Integer> firstArray;
    private List<Integer> secondArray;
    private List<Integer> thirdArray;

    ...
    ...
}
```

Then on the JavaScript side:

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "/myurl",
    data : {            
        myData: {
           "firstArray": firstArray,
           "secondArray": secondArray,
           "thirdArray": thirdArray
        }            
    },
    success : function(response) {
       // do something ... 
    },
    error : function(e) {
       alert('Error: ' + e);
    }
});
```

On the Java side, you can bind using `@ModelAttribute`:

```
public String controllerMethod(@ModelAttribute(value="myData") MyData myData) throws ParseException {
    ....
}
```

**EDIT**

Changed the `@RequestParam` annotation to use `myArray[]` instead of just `myArray`, since this change appears to have been made in Spring after this answer was first posted.

Comment: Thanks @vivin, how about multiple arrays? data: {myArray: a, myArray2: b, ...} ?

Comment: should myArray be a string like "myArray"?

Comment: @AlfredZhong I saw that you were using an array of `int`s, which is why I made it `Integer`. But there is no reason that you can't make it into `String[]` or `List<String>`.

Comment: @AlfredZhong I modified the second example to use `ModelAttribute` instead of `RequestParam`. `RequestParam` is for primitives.

Comment: I got a [object Object] error, I guess it is something related to the data when $ajex converts it to a string under the cover?

Comment: @AlfredZhong You must have some other error in your JavaScript. Are there any more details?

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping. I removed the ModelAttribute annotation and use just string to pass data, like in my own answer, and it works now!

Comment: @VivinPaliath Could you help me on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18102452/spring-mvc-415-unsupported-media-type

Comment: The key thing was you have to specify `[]` after variable name like `myArray[]`. Gosh, ate my half day.

Answer (score 7):

It is very simple passing such data to the Spring MVC controller, when you have in mind that data is being parsed from string. So if you want to get an array/list in the controller - pass a stringified version of the array:

```
public String method(
        @RequestParam(value = "stringParam") String stringParam,
        @RequestParam(value = "arrayParam") List<String> arrayParam) {
    ...
}
```

and the corresponding javascript with jQuery would be like:

```
$.post("/urlToControllerMethod",
    {
        "stringParam" : "test",
        "arrayParam" : [1, 2, 3, "test"].toString()
    }
);
```

**Note:** the parameter type

```
List<String> arrayParam
```

could be as well replaced with the array equivalent

```
String[] arrayParam
```

Answer (score 6):

Vivin Paliath doesn't work unless you use `myArray[]`

```
public String controllerMethod(@RequestParam(value="myArray[]") Integer[] myArray){
    ...
}
```

Comment: This seemed to work in our case too, whereas Vivin's answer didn't.

Comment: Looks like it was updated in recent versions on spring. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using spring mvc 4 then below will be the best approach

Jquery code

`var dataArrayToSend = [];
    dataArrayToSend.push("a");
    dataArrayToSend.push("b");
    dataArrayToSend.push("c");`

// ajax code

`$.ajax({
        contentType: "application/json",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(dataArrayToSend),
        url: "/appUrl",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('done');
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log('error while post');
        }

    });`

Spring controller code

`@RequestMapping(value = "/appUrl", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    void yourMethod(@RequestBody String[] dataArrayToSend) {
        for (String data : dataArrayToSend) {
            System.out.println("Your Data =>" + data);
        }
    }`

check this helps you or not!

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Fully tested solution

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "/myurl",
    data : {
        myArray: a //notice that "myArray" matches the value for @RequestParam
                   //on the Java side
    },
    success : function(response) {
       // do something ... 
    },
    error : function(e) {
       alert('Error: ' + e);
    }
}); 

@RequestMapping(value = "/save/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String controllerMethod(@RequestParam(value="myArray[]") List<Integer> myArray){
        System.out.println("My Array"+myArray.get(0));
        return "";
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I end up doing this and it works

In js,

```
var a = [];
a[0] = 1;
a[1] = 2;
a[2] = 3;


$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "/myurl",
    data : "a="+a,  //multiple array, just add something like "&b="+b ...
    success : function(response) {
       // do something ... 
    },
    error : function(e) {
       alert('Error: ' + e);
    }
});
```

java side, get a class to receive data, using lombok

@Setter @Getter
    public class MyData {
        private ArrayList a;
    }

then in the controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/repair_info", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView myControl(MyData myData) {
    // get data with myData object
}
```