# How to Read Numeric Array Value inside controller through HttpServletRequest

Tags: java, spring, jsp, servlets

Here is my code-

```
@controller
public ModelAndView ServiceContract(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
            HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) {      
        int sortId = Integer.parseInt(httpServletRequest.getParameter("sortId"));
                ModelMap map = new ModelMap();
        map.addAttribute("jsonString",jsonStringX); 
        return new ModelAndView(jsonView,map);
    }
```

inside my jsp file where from we are caaling this controller method.-

```
var sortId= [1,2, 3, 4 , 5];
```

how to obtain the values of it in controller?

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17560258/pass-array-data-from-javascript-in-browser-to-spring-mvc-controller-using-ajax

Answer (score 0):

```
String sortId = httpServletRequest.getParameter("sortId");
int sortIds[] = null;
if(sortId !=null){
       String array[] = sortId.split(",");
       sortIds = new int[array.length];
       for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
           try{
            sortIds[i] = Integer.parseInt(array[i]); 
           }catch(Exception e){
           }
       }
}
```

Now sortIds array have these values [1,2, 3, 4 , 5]