# 415 unsupported media type angularjs

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc

I am new beginner for Angular JS. I am trying to submit data from jsp page using angular js to spring mvc controller. I am trying to inject data to Pojo Object. But i am getting exception saying '415 unsupported'. Please help me where i went wrong .

JSP Page:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Testing Tool</title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var apps=angular.module('sampleApps',[]);
apps.controller('formController',function($scope, $http)
        {

    $scope.register=function()
    {
        var name=$scope.name;
        var address=$scope.address;
        alert(name + " , "+address);
        var formData = {
                  name       : name,
                  address    : address
              };
         $http({
                method : "POST",
                url : "userdetails",
                contentType: 'application/json',
                mimeType: 'application/json',
                /*   data: {name: name,address:address} */  
                 data:formData
                }).then(function mySucces(response) {
                 //$scope.myWelcome = response.data;
                 alert("Success");
                }, function myError(response) {
                    alert(response);
                 // $scope.myWelcome = response.statusText;
              });   

    };

        });
</script>
</head>
<body data-ng-app="sampleApps">
 <div  ng-controller="formController">
        Name: <br/>
        <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="name"/><br/>
        Address: <br/>
        <input type="text" name="address" ng-model="address"/><br/>

        <input type="button" value="submit"  ng-click="register()">
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/userdetails")
    public @ResponseBody User getUserDetails(HttpServletRequest request,@RequestBody User data)
    {
        System.out.println(data);
        return data;
    }
```

Pojo Class:

```
public class User implements Serializable
{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String name;
    private String address;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using Angular's `$http.post` shorthand instead of the longer notation that you're using. You might be messing it up by providing the `content-type` or `mime-type` manually.

Comment: Even if i use short cut also , i am getting same exception

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add **data:formData** => **data:JSON.stringify(formData)**

Check whether this helps you or not

Cheers!

Comment: Hi Chetan, I tried by adding data:JSON.stringify(formData). but still it didnt worked out. I added the jars jackson-jaxrs-1.9.2.jar
jackson-xc-1.9.2.jar

jersey-client-1.18.jar
jersey-json-1.18.jar
jersey-server-1.18.jar

jersey-core-1.18.jar
jersey-servlet-1.18.jar
jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar

Comment: please check from this url 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17560258/pass-array-data-from-javascript-in-browser-to-spring-mvc-controller-using-ajax/36174953#36174953

I have passed there an string array you can replace replace it with your object and also for safer side keep both object same name as user

Answer (score 0):

Based on your tag, I suposed you are using Spring MVC. Just add a new loggger for the spring web package. Raising the log level of the package `org.springframework.web` to DEBUG will give you the root cause of the 415 error.

Here is an exemple using logback :

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="org.springframework.web" level="DEBUG" />

    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

You'll also have a trace of all the request mapping resolved by your HTTP request.

Good luck.